# Merge function return into bbject: Spread vs Object.assign

Tags: javascript, function, object, spread

```
const filteredResults = reactive({});

function updater() {
  // return { ...filteredResults, ...useFilterInput(inputValues)}
  Object.assign(filteredResults, useFilterInput(inputValues))

}
```

### Previous Code Example:

While this works in my app:

```
...
Object.assign(filteredResults, useFilterInput(inputValues))
...
```

This does not:

```
...
return { ...filteredResults, ...useFilterInput(inputValues)}
...
```

Why

Comment: One creates a new object and returns it, the other assigns onto `filteredResults`.

Comment: Without your code it's hard to tell. However, it's likely that it's because
`Object.assign(filteredResults, useFilterInput(inputValues))` modifies `filteredResults` and `{ ...filteredResults, ...useFilterInput(inputValues)}` does not mutate any objects.

Comment: Thanks for the super fast response

True, that is not much context. I updated the question.
I have a form with multiple inputs and want, that filteredResults is updated (@input in vue3).
My goal is, to add to filteredResults all entered filters (... and filter the data).

To achieve that (what work at the moment fine, with Object.assign) can/should I achieve that with the spread operator too?
If yes, how would I write it.

Thanks for future response.

Comment: Thanks @Ivar, that is a great explanation.